# background image enlarge on small screen?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a problem that as screen become small background image become enlarge .I did google for it but failed to solve this issue.I am working on word press project using Avada theme. here is my [link](http://freeoglance.dk/client/manning/uddannelser/)

#### My CSS :

```
 .boost-din-uddannelser {
     background: url('http://arslankhalid.com/manning/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/12345_051.png');
     padding: 30px 22px;
     background-position: center center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-size: cover;
}
```

#### My HTML :

```
<div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes boost-din-uddannelser" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:20px;"><div class="fusion-column-wrapper"><div class="last-text">
<h3 data-fontsize="28" data-lineheight="28">BOOST DIN<br>
VÆRKTØJSKASSE<br>
SOM COACH ELLER<br>
LEDER</h3>
<p class="mid">Med to nye aften workshops.Få ny viden og værktøjer til at bruge coaching i virksomheder og til at udvikle teams.</p>
<p><a class="med" href="#">Læs mere</a></p>
</div>
<div class="fusion-clearfix"></div></div></div>
```

on enlarge screen it looks like this[image]

but on small screen it looks like [image]

Comment: You can give it max-height. Or can you make a fiddle that way we can be of better help

Comment: you can write media query for small screen and set image max-height

Comment: @IQBALPASHA max-height is not working over it .

Comment: @adeel_s I have provided link plz check it

Comment: let me know which css frame work you are using

Comment: @IQBALPASHA I am using avada theme .

Comment: What browsr, have you checked in all browsers?

Comment: @MiomirDancevic  I have checked on  chrome and Mozilla  .Issue is same on both browsers

Comment: Second is not and image :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `background-size: contain;` instead of `background-size: cover;`

> **cover:** Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background
>   image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within
>   the background positioning area
>
> **contain:** Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

Now how to make the div to a square that is equals to the both left and right of it?

```
width: 28vw;
height: 28vw;
```

When each of that divs get this width and height they would be always sqare's with same width.

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height

and at the Point where they should go under each other you use a media-query that set

```
transform: translate(-50%);
margin-left: 50%;
```

This centers the div responsive.

Maybe you have to play a bit with it.:)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11315706)

Comment: You are right, thanks i try to improve my answers in future.